# jQuery (Ajax) not working in Codeiginiter

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery. I am trying to call my controller using Ajax and get some information back but unable to do as the Ajax call doesn't get fired in console. Here is my code which goes in `<body>` of html

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>app-assets/js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).on('change','#plate_no',function(){
                        var plate_no = $('#plate_no').val();
                        alert(plate_no);
                        $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>Ajax_calls/datepicker',
                                data:'year='+plate_no,
                                success: function(response){
                                    $('#plate_no').html(response);
                                }
                            });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`JQuery` was being included at 02 places that is why it was not working